# How to put together different text files with equals first line - C#

Tags: c#

Please, check this:
A text files has this structure:

Text1.txt

```
000032;120128056
004                 00003000
009                 00256800
```

The first line is a parameter.
The other ones are items (from character 1 to 20) and its quantities (the last 8 digits).

I have a code that puts together all text files in a directory into a single final text file with all the information from the other ones, keepin' equal codes and adding the quantities.

```
string InventX = @"C:\Test";

if (!Directory.Exists(Test))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Test);
}

Dictionary<string, int> valores = new Dictionary<string, int>();

string diretorio = FormSelecionaPasta.Confirma;

String[] listaDeArquivos = Directory.GetFiles(diretorio);


if (listaDeArquivos.Length > 0)
{
    string caminhoArquivoDestino = @"C:\Test\Test.txt";

    FileStream arquivoDestino = File.Open(caminhoArquivoDestino, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    arquivoDestino.Close();

    foreach (String caminhoArquivo in listaDeArquivos)
    {
        //Lendo o arquivo atual
        foreach (var linhaArquivoAtual in File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo))
        {
            string Codigo = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(0, linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 8);
            string Quantidade = linhaArquivoAtual.Substring(linhaArquivoAtual.Length - 8, 8);

            //Verifica se o Codigo existe no dicionário
            if (valores.ContainsKey(Codigo))
                //Se existir o Codigo no dicionário, soma a quantidade
                valores[Codigo] = valores[Codigo] + Convert.ToInt32(Quantidade);

            else
                //Se nao existir o Codigo no dicionario, adiciona
                valores.Add(Codigo, Convert.ToInt32(Quantidade));
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(caminhoArquivoDestino, valores.Select(thales => thales.Key + thales.Value.ToString("00000000")).ToArray());

    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
}

else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error!");
}
```

But now, I would like to separate these files, by grouping files with the same first line.

I will try to example. I have these 3 files:

Text1.txt

```
000032;120128056
004                 00003000
009                 00256800
```

Text2.txt

```
000032;120128056
004                 00003000
009                 00256800
```

Text3.txt

```
000035;120128056
004                 00003000
009                 00256800
```

And I would like to get these final files:

```
000032120128056.txt
004                 00006000
009                 00513600

000035120128056
004                 00003000
009                 00256800
```

Got it? I really don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make a first quick-call into every file reading only the very first line and creating some sort of dictionary, like:

```
Dictionary<string, List<Stream>> Files;

foreach(var fileName in textFileNames)
{
   var fileStream = // open stream.
   var firstLine = // read first line

   if (Files.ContainsKey(firstLine))
      Files[firstLine].Add(fileStream);
   else
      Files.Add(firstLine, fileStream);              
}
```

After that, you can re-parse files by using the key collection from the dictionary or directly with a for-each (better performance).

```
foreach(var keyPair in Files)
{
   var outputFileName = "C:\\Temp\\" + keyPair.Key + ".txt";

   foreach(var stream in keyPair.Value)
   {
      // write (append) to your file.
      // close your stream.
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The approach should be

1. Load the data from files into memory (a collection/dictionary/etc)
2. Consolidate the data into one set by adding quantity for codes int same set (code1;code2)
3. Store the consolidated data back to file

To achieve the same, I created a class `TextFileInfo`.

***Note:*** I created the class instead of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>` (where inner `Dictionary` stores item code and its quantity, while the outer `Dictionary` stores the file code {`code1;code2`} and its items dictionary), because multiple files can contain the same set of code1 and code2 (as in your example text files text1 and text2)

The code that worked is provided below:

**1. Load the data from files into memory (a collection/dictionary/etc)**

```
private static List<TextFileInfo> LoadFiles()
{
    string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath), "*.txt");

    //The inner dictionary contains item code and their quantity. Outer dictionary store the code and their items details
    //Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> allRecords = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    List<TextFileInfo> allTextFileInfo = new List<TextFileInfo>();

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(file);

        TextFileInfo ti = new TextFileInfo();

        string codeLine = lines[0];
        string[] codeParts = codeLine.Split(';');
        ti.code1 = codeParts[0];
        ti.code2 = codeParts[1];

        for (int i = 1; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            string[] codeAndAmount = lines[i].Split('\t'); //assuming tab as the separator.
            string code = codeAndAmount[0];
            int quantity = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(codeAndAmount[1], out quantity))
            {
                if (ti.itemInfo.ContainsKey(code))
                    ti.itemInfo[code] += quantity;
                else
                    ti.itemInfo.Add(code, quantity);
            }
        }

        allTextFileInfo.Add(ti);
    }
    return allTextFileInfo;
}
```

**2. Consolidate the data into one set by adding quantity for codes int same set (code1;code2)**

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> ConsolidateRecords(List<TextFileInfo> allTextFileInfo)
{
    Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> consolidatedInfo = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();

    foreach (TextFileInfo ti in allTextFileInfo)
    {
        string key = ti.code1 + ti.code2;

        Dictionary<string, int> allItems = null;
        if (!consolidatedInfo.ContainsKey(key))
            consolidatedInfo.Add(key, new Dictionary<string, int>());

        allItems = consolidatedInfo[key];

        foreach (string code in ti.itemInfo.Keys)
        {
            int quantity = ti.itemInfo[code];

            if (allItems.ContainsKey(code))
                allItems[code] += quantity;
            else
                allItems.Add(code, quantity);
        }
    }

    return consolidatedInfo;
}
```

**3. Store the consolidated data back to file**

```
private static void SaveToFiles(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> consolidatedData)
{
    foreach (string key in consolidatedData.Keys)
    {
        string filename = key + ".log";

        Dictionary<string, int> items = consolidatedData[key];

        foreach (string code in items.Keys)
        {
            int quantity = items[code];

            File.AppendAllText(filename, code + "\t" + quantity.ToString("D8") + Environment.NewLine);
        }
    }
}
```

The output files that I got (using your input files) are:

```
000032120128056.log
    004 00006000
    009 00513600

000035120128056.log
    004 00003000
    009 00256800
```

***Note:** I've replaced the extension of the output files to `.log` as while reading the files, I'm reading all the `.txt` files.

Comment: Hello Manish. Thanks for all time spent doing this. It's look like that is exactly what I need. I am so sorry to tell that I really do not understand what you did. It`s my fault, I guess it`s a little advanced for me. Is it too much to ask you, please, to incorpore your solution into the code I sent as example. Thanks you so much in advance!